# How to convert VS2010 SQL Server Unit test project to VS 2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools, ssdt-bi

I have VS 2010 project with SQL Server unit tests. I need to convert them to VS2012. After much googling I found a msdn [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851204%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) which does not lay out the steps. The context menu on project does not contain anything related to project upgrade. After opening the project in 2012 you wont see your test sql unit test queries. If I open it in vs 2010 I see them. After opening the project in vs 2012 and if I create new sql unit test it will get pop-up box saying :

[image]

I have SSDTBI_VS21012 installed. Any idea how I go about converting my VS2010 project with SQL Server unit tests to VS2012?

Comment: This issue has now been fixed internally and will be available in an upcoming release of the SQL Server tools in VS. Thanks again for raising it. Kevin

Comment: @Kevin thanks. I will check it out when it comes out.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the product team, thanks for raising this. After a quick investigation, this looks like it is a regression introduced in the **July** release of SQL Server database tooling in Visual Studio.  Could you please file a connect bug for this issue at https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/CreateFeedback.aspx and use the category "Developer Tools(SSDT, BIDS, etc.)". We will treat this as high priority, and this is the best way to ensure it'll get tracked and you can see when it's fixed.

Unfortunately there is no workaround in the July/November releases as an overzealous check was added to avoid showing this option for all unit test projects, and we don't have an overrideable command. However, to unblock yourself you should be able to do one of two things:

**Workaround #1** uninstall the database tooling components and install an earlier version instead. Here's how:

- Go to Add/Remove Programs
- Uninstall "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools 2012", which is the overall installer, if present
- Uninstall "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - enu" (if you have English installed).
- You shouldn't have to uninstall "Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools Build Utilities - enu" if you're using July/November release as it's no longer relevant. However if you run into trouble, consider uninstalling this too.
- Install the April release of SQL Server tooling for VS2012 instead. The SSDTSetup.exe file to do this is found at http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/D/F/0DF6C816-A7D5-4C17-8B10-2061FC97D37E/EN/SSDTSetup.exe. Note if you are not using English, change the "/EN/" part of the URL to a different language such as DEU and it should allow you to download that language version.

**Workaround #2** Migrate to a new Unit Test Project
You can alternatively create a new SQL Unit Test Project and migrate your tests across:

- Create a unit test project based on a procedure in your SQL Project, or create a new Unit Test Project and go to "Add -> New Item -> SQL Server -> SQL Server Unit Test").
- When it opens the SQL Server Test Configuration dialog, be sure to enter valid values for the reference project and the connection string(s) - these should match your previous project
- Copy across your unit test files from the old project. If you build, it will fail due to a missing reference. We'll fix that next.
- Unload the project (right-click, unload project) and add the following snippet near the top:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <IncludeSsdtUnitTestAdapter>True</IncludeSsdtUnitTestAdapter>
  </PropertyGroup>
  ```
- Reload the project, and build. This should now pass as the adapter DLL used in migration will be included in the references.
- Lastly, run the tests and it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So, I have followed your instruction by uninstalling November installer and installed April version you provided. I still see the same result as before. Old sql unit tests are not showing and when creating new sql server unit test I get that same popup message. (I also uninstalled old build utilities as well).

Comment: Can you now see an option to convert in the context menu?

Comment: I do not see any menu item containing word "convert" in the context menu(right clicking on project or solution)

Comment: So if it's working, the option would be "Convert to SQL Server Unit Testing project" from the context menu. The fact this isn't here is unexpected as it certainly look like this was regressed post-April release. I am updating the answer with workaround #2, and again I'm sorry you're running into this

Comment: I ended up creating new unit test project and added sql server unit test in vs12 to manually move over my tests. It is little confusing in VS12 there is no database unit testing. It is sql server unit testing. But in VS10 there is database unit testing and sql server unit testing. So when I was in vs10 and created sql server unit testing thinking it is same as vs12 I was wrong. vs12 sql server unit testing is equivalent of vs10 database unit testing. Also I tried finding some sort of article explaining vs 2010's database unit testing vs sql server unit testing. I did not find any showing diff.